# Understanding reactive

Tags: android, reactive-programming, kotlin-coroutines

Recently kotlin flow is gaining a lot of attention. I have never done any reactive programming before so i thought now is a good time to learn it. Even though I have access to books and some articles I could not understand how to integrate it say on an existing app that does not have any rxjava. I tried looking for some sample but the only thing they would give me is very basic. Im really confuse about this reactive programming thing. For example, I have a list that I needed to get on database. Why would I use flow to get that data? If I visualize it as streams, that would give me one data each. While if I get that list I could get the whole list without waiting for each streams to come if I had use flow. I read a lot of articles about this kotlin flow, even rx java. But still, I wanted to understand why streams and how is it any different from other way like the example I just gave?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example, I have a list that I needed to get on database. Why would I use flow to get that data?

Well, that depends entirely on what you are using to access that database and how it uses `Flow`.

Let's suppose that you are using Room from the Android Jetpack. In that case, you can use Kotlin coroutines in two ways, via `suspend` functions and via `Flow`:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM stuff")
suspend fun getStuff(): List<Stuff>

@Query("SELECT * FROM stuff")
fun getStuffNowPlusChanges(): Flow<List<Stuff>>
```

In both cases, Room will do the database I/O on a background thread, and you can use coroutines to get the results on your desired thread (e.g., Android's main application thread). And initially, the results will be the same: you get a `List<Stuff>` representing the current contents of the `stuff` table.

The difference is what happens when the data changes.

In the case of the `suspend` function, you get just the one `List<Stuff>` from the point when you call the function. If you change the data in the `stuff` table, you would need to arrange to call that function again.

However, in the case of the `Flow`-returning function, if you change the data in the `stuff` table while you still have an observer of that `Flow`, **the observer will get a fresh `List<Stuff>` automatically**. You do not need to manually call some function again — Room handles that for you.

You will have to decide whether that particular feature is useful to you or not. And if you are using something else for database access, you will need to see if it supports `Flow` and how `Flow` is used.

Comment: So then, when someone said streams is that the latest update triggered and not the list giving its value one by one? Is this the correct assumption?

Comment: @thenewbie: I am uncertain if I understand your question. Suppose the `stuff` table has 5 rows. With Room, the `getStuffNowPlusChanges()` from the example in my question will deliver you a list of 5 `Stuff` items, one per row in the table. If, later, you insert another row, any active observers of the `Flow` will get a list of 6 `Stuff` items.

Comment: In the example, flow will give you the latest update of the changes, If I did changes on stuff table, flow would automatically give me the latest update assuming I am using realm. This update the is coming from flow, are these called streams? Or am I thinking of something entirely different.

Comment: @thenewbie: "flow would automatically give me the latest update assuming I am using realm" -- I have not used `Flow` with Realm, and I have very little Realm experience in general. If your concerns are specific to Realm, you may wish to ask a separate Stack Overflow question with a Realm tag. "This update the is coming from flow, are these called streams?" -- "stream" is not an unreasonable term to use for the series of results that you get from a `Flow`.

Comment: sorry I meant room. Finally understand it. I feel like it is no different from an event being fired from a button. It is almost the same.